# MicrosoftReportview error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I used MicrosoftReportview in my project , The reports are avalable in project folder.
When I run web site in Server (not VS development server) . It give this type of error.

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: The element 'buildProviders' cannot be defined below the application level.

Source Error:

Line 95:     
Line 96:    
Line 97:    
Line 98:     
Line 99:

Source File: C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\id_swcweb\web.config    Line: 97

Please Help me,Thanks

WEB.config

Asp.Net Configuration option in Visual Studio.
    A full list of settings and comments can be found in 
    machine.config.comments usually located in 
    \Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.x\Config 
-->

```
            <system.web>

                            <httpModules>

                                            <!--<add type="clsSeque" name="Qx"/>
                                            --> 
                            </httpModules>
                            <!---->
```

```
        Visual Basic options:
        Set strict="true" to disallow all data type conversions 
        where data loss can occur. 
        Set explicit="true" to force declaration of all variables.

                            <roleManager enabled="true"/>
    -->
                            <compilation debug="true">
                                            <assemblies>
                                                            <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                                                            <add assembly="System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
                                                            <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
                                                            <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
                                                            <add assembly="Infragistics2.Excel.v7.3, Version=7.3.20073.1043, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7DD5C3163F2CD0CB"/>
                                                            <add assembly="Infragistics2.Documents.v7.3, Version=7.3.20073.1043, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7DD5C3163F2CD0CB"/>
                                                            <add assembly="Infragistics2.Shared.v7.3, Version=7.3.20073.1043, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7DD5C3163F2CD0CB"/>                                                              
                                                            <add assembly="Infragistics2.Web.v7.3, Version=7.3.20073.1043, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7DD5C3163F2CD0CB"/>
                                                            <add assembly="Infragistics2.WebUI.Misc.v7.3, Version=7.3.20073.1043, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7DD5C3163F2CD0CB"/>
                                                            <add assembly="Infragistics2.WebUI.Shared.v7.3, Version=7.3.20073.1043, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7DD5C3163F2CD0CB"/>
                                                            <add assembly="Infragistics2.WebUI.UltraWebCalcManager.v7.3, Version=7.3.20073.1043, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7DD5C3163F2CD0CB"/>
                                                            <add assembly="Infragistics2.WebUI.UltraWebChart.v7.3, Version=7.3.20073.1043, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7DD5C3163F2CD0CB"/>
                                                            <add assembly="Infragistics2.WebUI.UltraWebGauge.v7.3, Version=7.3.20073.1043, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7DD5C3163F2CD0CB"/>
                                                            <add assembly="Infragistics2.WebUI.UltraWebGrid.DocumentExport.v7.3, Version=7.3.20073.1043, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7DD5C3163F2CD0CB"/>
                                                            <add assembly="Infragistics2.WebUI.UltraWebGrid.ExcelExport.v7.3, Version=7.3.20073.1043, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7DD5C3163F2CD0CB"/>
                                                            <add assembly="Infragistics2.WebUI.UltraWebGrid.v7.3, Version=7.3.20073.1043, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7DD5C3163F2CD0CB"/>
                                                            <add assembly="Infragistics2.WebUI.UltraWebListbar.v7.3, Version=7.3.20073.1043, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7DD5C3163F2CD0CB"/>
                                                            <add assembly="Infragistics2.WebUI.UltraWebNavigator.v7.3, Version=7.3.20073.1043, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7DD5C3163F2CD0CB"/>
                                                            <add assembly="Infragistics2.WebUI.UltraWebTab.v7.3, Version=7.3.20073.1043, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7DD5C3163F2CD0CB"/>
                                                            <add assembly="Infragistics2.WebUI.UltraWebToolbar.v7.3, Version=7.3.20073.1043, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7DD5C3163F2CD0CB"/>
                                                            <add assembly="Infragistics2.WebUI.WebCombo.v7.3, Version=7.3.20073.1043, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7DD5C3163F2CD0CB"/>
                                                            <add assembly="Infragistics2.WebUI.WebDataInput.v7.3, Version=7.3.20073.1043, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7DD5C3163F2CD0CB"/>
                                                            <add assembly="Infragistics2.WebUI.WebDateChooser.v7.3, Version=7.3.20073.1043, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7DD5C3163F2CD0CB"/>
                                                            <add assembly="Infragistics2.WebUI.WebHtmlEditor.v7.3, Version=7.3.20073.1043, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7DD5C3163F2CD0CB"/>
                                                            <add assembly="Infragistics2.WebUI.WebNavBar.v7.3, Version=7.3.20073.1043, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7DD5C3163F2CD0CB"/>
                                                            <add assembly="Infragistics2.WebUI.WebSchedule.v7.3, Version=7.3.20073.1043, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7DD5C3163F2CD0CB"/>
                                                            <add assembly="Infragistics2.WebUI.WebScheduleDataProvider.v7.3, Version=7.3.20073.1043, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7DD5C3163F2CD0CB"/>
                                                            <add assembly="Infragistics2.WebUI.WebSpellChecker.v7.3, Version=7.3.20073.1043, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7DD5C3163F2CD0CB"/>
                                            </assemblies>
                                            <buildProviders>
                                                            <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
                                            </buildProviders>

                            </compilation>
                            <!--        <compilation debug="false" strict="false" explicit="true" />
            -->
                            <pages>
                                            <namespaces>
                                                            <clear/>
                                                            <add namespace="System"/>
                                                            <add namespace="System.Collections"/>
                                                            <add namespace="System.Collections.Specialized"/>
                                                            <add namespace="System.Configuration"/>
                                                            <add namespace="System.Text"/>
                                                            <add namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions"/>
                                                            <add namespace="System.Web"/>
                                                            <add namespace="System.Web.Caching"/>
                                                            <add namespace="System.Web.SessionState"/>
                                                            <add namespace="System.Web.Security"/>
                                                            <add namespace="System.Web.Profile"/>
                                                            <add namespace="System.Web.UI"/>
                                                            <add namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls"/>
                                                            <add namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts"/>
                                                            <add namespace="System.Web.UI.HtmlControls"/>
                                            </namespaces>
                            </pages>
                            <!--
        The <authentication> section enables configuration 
        of the security authentication mode used by 
        ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
    -->

                            <!--
        The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
        of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
        during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
        it enables developers to configure html error pages 
        to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
        <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
    </customErrors>
    -->
                            <httpHandlers>
                                            <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" validate="false"/>
                            </httpHandlers>
            </system.web>
            <appSettings>
                            <add key="ReportServer" value="http://srv01/reportserver$mssql2005"></add>

                            <!--Report Server Credentiols -->
                            <add key="MyReportViewerUser" value="reportserver"/>
                            <add key="MyReportViewerPassword" value="reportserver"/>
                            <add key="MyReportViewerDomain" value="10.227.00.00"/>
                            <!-- -->
            </appSettings>
            <!-- <location allowOverride="true" inheritInChildApplications="true">
       <appSettings>
           <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-AutoStart" value="true" />
           <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-Sleep" value="60000" />
           <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-Age" value="120000" />
       </appSettings>
   </location>-->
            <system.net>
                            <mailSettings>

                            </mailSettings>
            </system.net>
```

Answer (score 2):

Place the `web.config` in the very folder you've defined the web application is using in the IIS and not a **subfolder**.

And make sure one of the following:

1) web.config is in the root folder of your website and not in any subfolder

OR

2) Try converting that subfolder into an application in IIS.

Comment: +1 yep, this error occurs also when opening a folder as a website in visual studio 2010+. Open it from the root folder